# SIGABRT crash when trying to call JSON data from URL

Tags: ios, xcode, json, sigabrt

I am working on an app that brings JSON data into a TableView. But at the moment the moment the code for the JSON operation starts, the app crashes with a SIGABRT error. Below is the code I'm working with (minus the actual URL for security reasons, of course):

```
// START - CONNECT TO JSON FILE ON SERVER AND DOWNLOAD INFORMATION
- (void)fetchTags
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"URL goes here..."]];

        NSError* error;
        //tags = how many objects there are in the JSON file containing data
        tags = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];
```

NSDictionary *tagz = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];

```
    tags = [tagz objectForKey:@"name"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
// END - CONNECT TO JSON FILE ON SERVER AND DOWNLOAD INFORMATION

//START - NUMBER OF ROWS TO GENERATE
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tags.count;
}
//END - NUMBER OF ROWS TO GENERATE


// START - PULL IN INFORMATION FROM JSON AND DISPLAY IN CELLS
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TagCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *tag = [tags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *name = [tag objectForKey:@"name"];

        if ([tag objectForKey:@"name"] != NULL)

    cell.textLabel.text = name;

    return cell;
    }
// END - PULL IN INFORMATION FROM JSON AND DISPLAY IN CELLS
```

Here is the JSON data that URL points to:
{"sessionid": "0.97880095305420120818085118", "option2": "", "logonresult": "ACCEPT", "projects": [{"projid": 2012011101, "name": "\u5909\u66f4\u5c65\u6b74\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8"}, {"projid": 2011101401, "name": "20111014-01"}, {"projid": 201111001, "name": "\u5c3e\u7530\u90b8\u30ea\u30d5\u30a9\u30fc\u30e0" }], "option1": ""}

Here is the full error returned on crash:
2012-08-19 00:32:59.421 CameraTest[2141:707] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16f750
2012-08-19 00:32:59.423 CameraTest[2141:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16f750'

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong or refer me to a tutorial that might help?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the following code placed in (void)fetchTags fixed the crash, but I'm still having trouble as data is not being pulled into my cells:

```
    NSDictionary *tagz = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];

    tags = [tagz objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: `NSString *name = [tag objectForKey:@"name"];
    {
        if ([tag objectForKey:@"name"] != NULL)

    cell.textLabel.text = name;

    return cell;
    }}` what's the first curly bracket is for? (Just before if condition)

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I just edited my code, removing the first curly bracket and the corresponding closing one. Still getting the same error though.

Comment: Is JSONObjectWithData: returning an NSArray?

Comment: I would also suggest to check whether `tags.count != 0`. Please do a `NSLog(@"Tags Count: %d", tags.count);` and verify it.

Comment: What does `tags` reference to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty much sure that `tags` is either an `NSArray` or an `NSMutableArray`, where it should be an `NSDictionary`.

The reason you're app is crashing is since `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];` returns NSDictionary objects and `NSDictionary` doesn't have the `objectAtIndex:` method, it triggers an exception.

You can do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *tagz = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];

tags = [tagz objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Thanks @OhhMee this did help stop the crash. I added your tagz code under (void)fetchTags (see above). But still one problem left to go as no data is filling my cells. Any ideas why the data isn't coming in?

Comment: Try `tags = [tagz objectForKey:@"projects"];`. "projects" in an array of dictionaries in your JSON data, so that is probably what you want.